# Check if a user is streaming in a discord vc

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I would like my bot to detect if someone is streaming to a channel using discord's `Go Live!` feature for voice channels.

Then only let people connect to a waiting room, to avoid people spamming join and disturbing the stream. The only problem is that the documentation shows that you can check if they are streaming on twitch or youtube etc. How do I use my bot to detect if someones streaming to a discord channel?

The only code I've tried is:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
  print(before)
  print(after)
```

but I got no output at all from it, not even an error message.

Comment: Are you trying to check if one specific user is live?

Comment: @DapperDuck No i just want to check if anyone is live in a specific channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `self_stream` attribute of a `VoiceState` instance to check if a user is currently streaming to a voice channel.

Example flagging up when a member stops or starts streaming:

```
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, prev, cur):
    if prev.channel and cur.channel:  # If a user is connected before and after the update
        if prev.self_stream != cur.self_stream:
            # cur.self_stream will return True whether they're currently streaming
            print("User's self-stream updated!")
```

As usual, you'll be able to get their current channel and such through other attributes of `VoiceState`:

```
cur.channel  # etc.
```

---

### References:

- [`VoiceState.self_stream`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceState.self_stream)
- [`VoiceState.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceState.channel)
- [`on_voice_state_update()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_voice_state_update)